# I want to transform my json using jolt. I have a list of type strings. i want to split the string and change to key value pair

Tags: json, jolt

Here is my **input** format :

```json
{
  "id": "abc",
  "type": "car",
  "size": "small",
  "carInformation": [
    {
      "Licence": {
        "code": "AP123"
      },
      "additionalInformation": [
        "Brought successfully",
        "/identification/",
        "/Rate/30000",
        "/Date/2023-01-11"
        
      ]
    }
  ],
"carInformation": [
    {
      "Licence": {
        "code": "AP124"
      },
      "additionalInformation": [
        "Brought unsuccessfully",
        "/identification/98981",
        "/Rate/30030",
        "/Date/2023-01-12"
        
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

I want to iterate through the carInformation and additionalInformation and split the string based on "/" and store it as key, value pair. if the string does not have "/" then store it with key as DATA{number} and value as the string.

This is my **expected output** :

```json
{
  "cars": {
    "carInformation": {
      "identification": [ "98989", "98981" ],
      "Rate": [ "30000", "30030" ],
      "Date": [ "2023-01-11", "2023-01-12" ],
      "DATA1": "Brought successfully",
      "DATA2": "Brought unsuccessfully"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This input is not a valid JSON, Because you have more than 1 `carInformation` key in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumingly converting your current input to

```json
{
  "id": "abc",
  "type": "car",
  "size": "small",
  "carInformation1": [
    {
      "Licence": {
        "code": "AP123"
      },
      "additionalInformation": [
        "Brought successfully",
        "/identification/98989",
        "/Rate/30000",
        "/Date/2023-01-11"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "carInformation2": [
    {
      "Licence": {
        "code": "AP124"
      },
      "additionalInformation": [
        "Brought unsuccessfully",
        "/identification/98981",
        "/Rate/30030",
        "/Date/2023-01-12"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

since it violates the validity rule to be a JSON by duplicated keys, and based on the desired output having `DATA1`,`DATA2`.

In this case, you can use the following transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "carInformation*": {
        "*": {
          "additional*": {
            "*": {
              "/*/*": { // the values those have slashes
                "@": "cars.car&(3,1).&(1,1).&(1,2)"
              },
              "*": "cars.car&(2,1).DATA&(4,1).&" // the values those don't have slashes
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "$": "&4.&3.&2" // matching keys($ wildcard) against values(&2) while adding outer nodes (&4.&3)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

where the key **`"/*/*"`** is used in order to split the related values by first or second asterisks

( eg. **`&(..,1)`**, **`&(..,2)`** )

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]